# Ubuntu host. Windows XP VM. Internet Access for VM via host

Tags: networking, internet, vmware, connection

I'm trying to grant internet access to my virtual machines running Windows XP. Unfortunately, they aren't connecting for some reason. In the past, when I've used a Windows host, VMWare creates it's own network interfaces which I can then either assign IP Addresses/Bridge/Whatever and this normally allows the connection.

Unfortunately, due to the way in which XP works, I need internet access in order to register the product in the first place, so I can't even change any of the settings on the VM's!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These settings are from VirtualBox, but usually they works om VMWare too.

Open the VM `Settings`, select `Network` and then check if:

- your adapter is enabled (`Enable Network Adapter` is checked)
- `Attached to` value is `Bridged Adapter`
- in Advanced, `Adapter Type` is `PCnet-FAST III (Arm79C973)`

Then restart.

Comment: Worked, thanks for your help. Although I couldn't change the `Adapter Type` as it's not present in VMWare12, or at least my copy/VM. I'd already tried changing the value to Bridged yesterday, but for some reason it didn't like it.